# fetch database metadata from laravel

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, laravel-4, breeze

Is there an easy way to fetch db metadata from laravel?

I was looking to leverage Breezejs EntityManager, but I need to fetch the metadata on my DB and I was hoping I wouldn't have to define this twice.

***Update***

specifically, I'm looking to acquire schema metadata about entity structure

- http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand
- http://json-schema.org/examples.html

Comment: what `db metadata` are you referring to?  There isn't a lot to go on with your question.

Comment: Maybe someone else can have a go here as I still don't understand what is being asked here

Comment: Why not just write the metadata by hand as mentioned in the link you posted?  It's extremely simple considering the alternative is to get Laravel or w/e to serve up a JSON representation of your metadata.

Comment: What metadata are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There's not direct method, but if you are curious and don't mind using DataMapper instead of ActiveRecord (switching from Eloquent to Doctrine) there's [this repo](https://github.com/adrotec/breeze.server.php) that leverages support for BreezeJS generating the entity metadata from Doctrine ORM annotated models.  They implemented an Employee Directory [sample app](http://emp-directory.herokuapp.com/), that can have [laravel](https://github.com/adrotec/emp-directory/tree/master/server/laravel) as one of the server variations.

I'm writing the metadata by hand for now (it's really [not complicated](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/metadata-by-hand-details.html)), You can also write some code that can infer the models schema by parsing some query like 'DESCRIBE table_name' so you can stick with Eloquent.

EDIT: The answer to this question shows this *DESCRIBE* approach [Can Eloquent models retrieve metadata on their rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700739/can-eloquent-models-retrieve-metadata-on-their-rows)